# Using complex objects in DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have several BigQuery tables that we're reading from through DataFlow. At the moment those tables are flattened and a lot of the data is repeated. In Dataflow, all operations must be idempotent, so any output only depends on the input to the function, there's no state kept anywhere else. This is why it makes sense to first group all the records together that belong together and in our case, this probably means creating complex objects.

Example of A complex object (there are many other types like this). We can have millions of instances of each type obviously:

```
Customer{
   customerId
   address {
      street
      zipcode
      region
      ... 
   }
   first_name
   last_name
   ...
   contactInfo: {
       "phone1": {type, number, ... },
       "phone2": {type, number, ... }
   }
}
```

The examples we found for DataFlow only process very simple objects and the examples demonstrate counting, summing and averaging.

In our case, we eventually want to use DataFlow to perform more complicated processing in accordance with sets of rules. Those rules apply to the full contact of a customer, invoice or order for example and eventually produce a whole set of indicators, sums and other items.

We considered doing this 100% in BigQuery, but this gets very messy very quickly due to the rules that apply per entity.

At this time I'm still wondering whether DataFlow is really the right tool for this job. There are almost no examples for dataFlow that demonstrate how it's used for these type of more complex objects with one or two collections. The closest I found was the use of a "LogMessage" object for log processing, but this didn't have any collections and therefore didn't do any hierarchical processing.

The biggest problem we're facing is hierarchical processing. We're reading data like this:

```
customerid ... street zipcode region ... phoneid type number
 1               a       b       c        phone1  1    555-2424
 1               a       b       c        phone2  1    555-8181
```

And the first operation should be group those rows together to construct a single entity, so we can make our operations idempotent. What is the best way to do that in DataFlow, or point us to an example that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any object as the elements in a Dataflow pipeline. The [TrafficMaxLaneFlow example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TrafficMaxLaneFlow.java#L104) uses a complex object (although it doesn't have a collection).

In your example you would do a [`GroupByKey`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key) to group the elements. The result is a `KV<K, Iterable<V>>`. The `KV` here is just an object and has a collection-like value inside. You could then take that `KV<K, Iterable<V>>` and turn it into whatever kind of objects you wanted.

The only thing to be aware of is that if you have very few elements that are really big you may run into some parallelism limits. Specifically, each element needs to be small enough to be processed on a single machine.

You may also be interested in [`withoutFlatteningResults`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Read.Bound#withoutResultFlattening--) on `BigQueryIO`. It only supports reading from a query (rather than a table) but it should provide the results without flattening.

Comment: We're not using windows, so for a batch job, when we apply groupbykey, are we guaranteed to have all related records available in the "Iterable<V>" across the global dataset?

Comment: As long as you are not using Windows or Triggers, yes -- all values with the same key will be present in the `Iterable<V>`.